# Typescript function overloading based on input arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading

I'm looking for a way to override or overload a specific group of functions.

Here's an example

```
const operationA = ({a, b, c}) => 'alpha';
const operationB = ({a, b }) => 'beta';
const operationC = ({a}) => 'gamma';

const operation = compose([operationA, operationB, operationC]);

operation({a}) // 'gamma'
operation({a, b}) // 'beta'
operation({a, b, c}) // 'alpha'
```

Is there a way to do this functionality within typescript?

Comment: Are you asking how to write the `compose()` function in TypeScript?  Since TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, you need to be able to write an untyped `compose()` in JavaScript.  How would you propose, at runtime, to determine which overload to use?

Comment: Also, while [object property shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Basic_assignment) are neat, it's hard to understand what's going on in this question. As written, the code doesn't compile (even if `compose()` were given to us). Are `a`, `b`, and `c` supposed to be in-scope variables?  In `operationA()` etc, are the types of `a` etc., supposed to be `any`?

Answer (score 2):

(In the following I'm using TypeScript 3.2)

The main issue with your question, if I understand it, is the difficulty of choosing the right overload at runtime.  It is [not one of TypeScript's goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (see Non-Goal #5) to compile type information from TypeScript into JavaScript.  The type system added by TypeScript is completely erased at runtime.  So, if you want to write `compose()` to take a list of functions, somehow you have to be able to inspect those functions at runtime to determine which one should be called on a particular argument.  That functionality really doesn't exist in JavaScript, though.  Well, you can kind of use the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property of a function to see how *many* arguments it expects, but in the examples you gave, each function takes exactly one argument.  So we can't use that approach here.

One possible way forward is to add a [property](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#properties-declarations-on-functions) to each function.  This property would be a method that takes a potential set of arguments and returns `true` if those arguments are valid for the function, and `false` if they are not.  Essentially you're manually adding the necessary inspection ability that is missing from the language.

If we do this, we can make `compose()` accept a list of such "argument validating functions", like this:

```
type ArgValidatingFunction =
  ((...args: any[]) => any) & { validArgs(...args: any): boolean };

type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends
  ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

function compose<F extends ArgValidatingFunction[]>(...fn: F): UnionToIntersection<F[number]>;
function compose(...fn: ArgValidatingFunction[]): Function {
  return Object.assign(
    (...args: any[]) => (fn.find(f => f.validArgs(...args))!(...args)),
    { validArgs: (...args: any[]) => fn.some(f => f.validArgs(...args)) }
  );
}
```

The type signature for `compose` accepts a list of `ArgValidatingFunction` arguments and returns the [intersection of its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type).  TypeScript represents [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) as an order-dependent intersection of signatures.  I can't 100% guarantee that the compiler will produce the same overload order as the functions passed in, but it seems to work in my testing.

The implementation of `compose` makes use of the `ArgValidatingFunction`'s `validArgs` method, and does a [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the passed-in functions to choose the proper function.  I also implement a `validArgs()` method on the returned function so that the return value of `compose()` is also an `ArgValidatingFunction` (which is good because the type signature claims that it is).

Now we can try to use it, but it's not trivial... we have to add those methods:

```
const operationA = ({ a, b, c }: { a: any, b: any, c: any }): 'alpha' => 'alpha';
operationA.validArgs = (...args: any[]) => 
  (args.length === 1) && ('a' in args[0]) && ('b' in args[0]) && ('c' in args[0]);

const operationB = ({ a, b }: { a: any, b: any }): 'beta' => 'beta';
operationB.validArgs = (...args: any[]) => 
  (args.length === 1) && ('a' in args[0]) && ('b' in args[0]);

const operationC = ({ a }: { a: any }): 'gamma' => 'gamma';
operationC.validArgs = (...args: any[]) => 
  (args.length === 1) && ('a' in args[0]);
```

Here we go:

```
const operation = compose(operationA, operationB, operationC);

const beta = operation({ a: 3, b: 3 }); // "beta" at compile time;
console.log(beta); // "beta" at runtime
```

Looks like it works both at compile time and runtime.

---

So that's one way to go.  It's not easy or pretty, but maybe it works for your (or someone's) use case.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An approach, which maybe you have already evaluated is to use an `Interface` as input of your main `operation` method, and then dispatch the right sub methods depending on the input.

So something like:

```
interface OperationArgs {
 a: string;
 b?: string;
 c?: string;
}
```

So the first value is mandatory, the other two are optionals.

Inside your `operation` method you can do something like:

```
public operation(inp: OperationArgs) {
  if (inp.c) {
    return this.operationC(inp);
  }
  if (inp.b) {
    return this.operationB(inp);
  }
  return this.operationA(inp);
}
```

Another approach is to use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) but they are not fully supported yet in JS (explorer is missing). You could create a class which returns a `Proxy` instance, and trap the `operation` methods using the `get` method of the handler. Depending on the given props, you will actually call the right method on the instance.